# How to calculate log-likelihood for prospect theory? How to specify CDF and error function?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, cumulative-distribution-function

I want to estimate parameters of prospect theory using Maximum Likelihood. My data structure and my estimation procedure closely follow [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00355-018-1111-y). I attached my R code below. Note the definitions of CDF, error function, and likelihood.

```
# Precision [in study design]
PRECISION = 5

weight = function(p_x, delta, gamma){
  # when gain, delta = pessimism
  # when loss, delta = optimism
  # gamma = sensitivity to probability changes
  w = exp(-delta * (-log(p_x))^gamma)
  
  return(w)
}

u = function(x, alpha, lambda=1){
  # lambda: loss aversion when > 1
  u = ifelse(x >= 0, v(x, alpha), -lambda * v(-x, alpha))
  
  return(u)
}

v = function(x, alpha){
  # gain: alpha > 0 = risk aversion
  # loss: alpha > 0 = risk seeking
  v = ifelse(alpha != 0, (1 - exp(-alpha*x))/(1 - exp(-alpha)), x)
  
  return(v)
}

prospect_gain = function(x, y, p_x, alpha_gain, delta_gain, gamma_gain){

  prospect = weight(p_x, delta_gain, gamma_gain) * (u(x, alpha_gain) - u(y, alpha_gain)) + u(y, alpha_gain)
  
  return(prospect)
}

prospect_loss = function(x, y, p_x, alpha_loss, delta_loss, gamma_loss, lambda){

  prospect = weight(p_x, delta_loss, gamma_loss) * (u(x, alpha_loss, lambda) - u(y, alpha_loss, lambda)) + u(y, alpha_loss, lambda)
  
  return(prospect)
}

prospect_mix = function(x, y, p_x, alpha_gain, alpha_loss, delta_gain, delta_loss,
                        gamma_gain, gamma_loss, lambda){

  prospect = weight(p_x, delta_gain, gamma_gain) * u(x, alpha_gain) + weight(1-p_x, delta_loss, gamma_loss) * u(y, alpha_loss, lambda)
  
  return(prospect)
}

# Returns theoretical indifference value
prospect = function(x, y, p_x,
                    param){
  
  alpha_gain = param[1]
  alpha_loss = param[2]
  delta_gain = param[3]
  delta_loss = param[4]
  gamma_gain = param[5]
  gamma_loss = param[6]
  lambda = param[7]
  
  #' This block ensures that x and y are assigned correctly according to this:
  #' "Prospects involving only non-negative outcomes (x >= y >= 0) are called gain
  #' prospects. Prospects involving only negative outcomes (x <= y <= 0) are called
  #' loss prospects. Prospects involving both positive and negative outcomes 
  #' (x > 0 > y) are called mixed prospects." (p. 167)
  #' 

  xy = data.frame(x, y)
  x = ifelse(sign(xy$x) + sign(xy$y) > 0, pmax(xy$x, xy$y), # Gain
             ifelse(sign(xy$x) + sign(xy$y) < 0, pmin(xy$x, xy$y), # Loss
                    pmax(xy$x, xy$y))) # Mixed
  
  y = ifelse(sign(xy$x) + sign(xy$y) > 0, pmin(xy$x, xy$y), # Gain
             ifelse(sign(xy$x) + sign(xy$y) < 0, pmax(xy$x, xy$y), # Loss
                    pmin(xy$x, xy$y))) # Mixed
  
  # Calculate indifference value
  prospect = ifelse(x>=0 & y>=0,
                    # Gain
                    prospect_gain(x, y, p_x,
                                  alpha_gain,
                                  delta_gain,
                                  gamma_gain),
                    ifelse(x<=0 & y<=0,
                           # Loss
                           prospect_loss(x, y, p_x,
                                         alpha_loss,
                                         delta_loss,
                                         gamma_loss,
                                         lambda),
                           # Mixed
                           prospect_mix(x, y, p_x,
                                        alpha_gain, alpha_loss,
                                        delta_gain, delta_loss,
                                        gamma_gain, gamma_loss,
                                        lambda)))
  
  return(prospect)
}

phi = function(x, mu, sigma){
  erf = function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1
  phi = 1/2 * (1 + erf((x - mu)/sigma * sqrt(2)))
  return(phi)
}

# Likelihood function
l = function(v_obs, prospect, sigma, a=PRECISION/2){

  l = phi(v_obs + a, prospect, sigma) - phi(v_obs - a, prospect, sigma)
  return(l)
}

# Calculate log-likelihood
ll = function(param, data){
  
  alpha_gain = param[1]
  alpha_loss = param[2]
  delta_gain = param[3]
  delta_loss = param[4]
  gamma_gain = param[5]
  gamma_loss = param[6]
  lambda = param[7]
  sigma = param[8]

  prospects = prospect(data$x, data$y, data$p_x, param)

  likelihood = l(v_obs=data$v_obs, prospect=prospects, sigma=sigma)
  
  log_likelihood = sum(log(likelihood))
  
  return(-log_likelihood)
}

### Simulation
param_sim = c(alpha_gain=0.01, alpha_loss=0.002,
             delta_gain=1.053, delta_loss=1.106,
             gamma_gain=0.724, gamma_loss=0.696,
             lambda=1.962, sigma=0.5)

# Example trials
x_gain = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 75, 100)
x_loss = c(-100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -50, -75, -100)
#TODO: Mixed
x = c(x_gain, x_loss)

y_gain = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 25)
y_loss = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -25, -25)
y = c(y_gain, y_loss)

p_x = rep(c(.1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .5, .5, .5), 2)

# Simulated responses
simulate_response = function(x, y, p_x, param){
  # Returns value as it will be returned in the experiment:
  # Experiment yields interval of PRECISION in which true value lies
  # Function returns middle of that interval
  
  v_obs = prospect(x, y, p_x, param)
  upper = ceiling(v_obs/PRECISION)*PRECISION
  lower = trunc(v_obs/PRECISION)*PRECISION
  return((upper + lower)/2)
}

v_obs = simulate_response(x, y, p_x, param_sim)

# Simulated data
df = data.frame(x, y, p_x, v_obs)

# Check for ll close to zero when true values are observed
ll(param_sim, data=df)

# Test parameters
param_test = c(alpha_gain=0.011, alpha_loss=0.002,
              delta_gain=1.053, delta_loss=1.106,
              gamma_gain=0.724, gamma_loss=0.696,
              lambda=1.962, sigma=0.5)

l(df$v_obs, prospect(df$x, df$y, df$p_x, param_test), 0.5)

ll(param_test, data=df)

# Optimization
start_param = c(alpha_gain=0.1, alpha_loss=0.002,
                delta_gain=1.053, delta_loss=1.106,
                gamma_gain=0.724, gamma_loss=0.696,
                lambda=1.962, sigma=0.5)

optim(par=start_param, fn=ll, data=df)
```

I am encountering two problems:

1. I simulated some data. My negative log-likelihood function keeps returning infinity for almost all parameters that are not exactly the parameters that I used for simulating the data.
2. The optimization using optim() in R fails when I am not using the true parameter values (from my simulated data) as starting parameters - which would not be possible or meaningful with real data and which probably relates to problem 1. Optim tells me that the function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters.

There are two possible sources of my problems:

1. I am new to error functions and cdf. Are they specified correctly?
2. In the paper, they are not using simple Maximum Likelihood estimation, but they use maximization of simulated likelihood and they estimate the required integral using Halton draws. I am not familiar with these concepts. Would they solve my problems? Would they lead to a more precise estimation?

I would also be grateful for any alternative methods for estimating these parameters or simplifications of the model. I am mostly interested in risk aversion.